# A riddle to invite reflection?

Tags: riddle, word

I have an eye, but cannot c.

Three of are are inside of me.

I share three things with mother,

Two with brink,

And one with rage.

What am I?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are a

> MIRROR

because

> You have an **I**, but no c
>  Three of **R** are inside of you
>  You share three letters with **MO**the**R**
>  Two with b**RI**nk
>  and one with **R**age.
>
> And a mirror shows you your reflection, which the title of the puzzle references.